# List C# keywords

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to find a way to list all C# keywords. I need to make a comparison, such as:

```
if (key == "if" || key == "while" || <further_comparisons>)
{
     // do something
}
```

It would be way better to do it by searching in a list of those keywords, and I would like to do it without typing them.

I'm looking at System.CodeDom namespace to see if I can find something.

If any of you could tell me where I could find it, I would really appreciate it.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/index

Comment: You can't use the selected answer to get a list of key words.

Comment: @toddmo That answer makes sense "searching in a list of those keywords"

Comment: @faceturn, He said he doesn't want to have to type them out individually. That answer doesn't save him from that, and doesn't provide any way to list (enumerate / check all / compare all) the keywords, which is the question, right?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use

`using Microsoft.CSharp;`

```
 CSharpCodeProvider cs = new CSharpCodeProvider();
```

then, you can use

```
var test = cs.IsValidIdentifier("if") //return false
```

Comment: There are all sorts of strings that aren't valid identifiers that aren't keywords.

Comment: Thank you!! It suited my needs!

Answer (score 1):

You'll find a list of all keywords in the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/index

```
new string[]
{
    "bool", "byte", "sbyte", "short", "ushort", "int", "uint", "long", "ulong", "double", "float", "decimal",
    "string", "char", "void", "object", "typeof", "sizeof", "null", "true", "false", "if", "else", "while", "for", "foreach", "do", "switch",
    "case", "default", "lock", "try", "throw", "catch", "finally", "goto", "break", "continue", "return", "public", "private", "internal",
    "protected", "static", "readonly", "sealed", "const", "fixed", "stackalloc", "volatile", "new", "override", "abstract", "virtual",
    "event", "extern", "ref", "out", "in", "is", "as", "params", "__arglist", "__makeref", "__reftype", "__refvalue", "this", "base",
    "namespace", "using", "class", "struct", "interface", "enum", "delegate", "checked", "unchecked", "unsafe", "operator", "implicit", "explicit"
};
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is exactly what I don't want to do :)

Comment: @Mari Faleiros this _should_ be what you want to do. Afterall, the list doesn't change very often. And it is the most efficient way. I'd just use a `HashSet<string>` instead of an array.

Answer (score 1):

[`CSharpCodeProvider`](https://searchcode.com/file/115723866/mcs/class/referencesource/System/compmod/microsoft/csharp/csharpcodeprovider.cs) has the logic to do this. But you must call it with reflection. It contains an `IsKeyword` function. More specifically, it has the actual list of keywords which `IsKeyword` uses.

```
private static readonly string[][] keywords
```

Comment: I see, I'll test your solution! Thank you!!

Comment: Also found here: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/microsoft/csharp/csharpcodeprovider.cs,145

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Roslyn, you can do this with the [Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp) nuget package.

After adding this package, your code becomes:

```
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
if (SyntaxFacts.GetKeywordKind(key) != SyntaxKind.None || SyntaxFacts.GetContextualKeywordKind(key) != SyntaxKind.None)
{
    // do something
}
```

If you need this to be as fast as possible, use a static field like:

```
private static readonly HashSet<string> Keywords =
    SyntaxFacts.GetKeywordKinds().Select(SyntaxFacts.GetText).ToHashSet();
```

Then, your code becomes:

```
if (Keywords.Contains(key))
{
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using reflection and a dependency on implementation details, you can use the static `IsKeyWord` method of the [Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator Class](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/microsoft/csharp/csharpcodeprovider.cs,38aee7ab2939bf42,references).

```
using System;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using Microsoft.CSharp;
using System.Reflection;

internal class CS
    {
    private static MethodInfo methIsKeyword;
    static CS()
        {
        using (CSharpCodeProvider cs = new CSharpCodeProvider())
            {
            FieldInfo infoGenerator = cs.GetType().GetField("generator", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

            object gen = infoGenerator.GetValue(cs);
            methIsKeyword = gen.GetType().GetMethod("IsKeyword", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            }
        }
    public static bool IsKeyword(string input)
        {
        return Convert.ToBoolean(methIsKeyword.Invoke(null, new object[] { input.Trim() }));
        }
    }
```

Example usage:

```
bool isKeyword = CS.IsKeyword("if");
```