# Check if a string is a reserved keyword

Tags: c#, .net

C# has a number of reserved keywords such as `class`, `string`, `struct`, `ref` and more.

A complete list of reserved keywords can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/).

Is there a way to check a string for these reserved keywords, without manually maintaining a list of them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List C# keywords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44728159/list-c-sharp-keywords). Specifically, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44728510/14956277) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44731796/14956277).

Comment: Thanks for the links! It was actually [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64357583/5953220) that helped the most -- I'm working with source generators.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16497650/17034

Comment: It's worth noting that after v1 of the language, many more words became significant to the language (like, for instance "yield" and "async"). But they are context dependent; they have meaning where the language uses them, but programmers can still use them as variable names

Answer (score 1):

The [CSharpCodeProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) has a method [IsValidIdentifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.codedom.compiler.codedomprovider.isvalididentifier?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) that accepts a string as input and will return `false` if the string is invalid for use as an identifier (including because it is a reserved keyword).  Technically this will check more than just reserved keywords, but it is the one of the easiest ways to check against reserved keywords programmatically.

```
CSharpCodeProvider codeProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
bool wordIsReserved = codeProvider.IsValidIdentifier("public") == false;
```